# Primefaces remoteCommand refreshing datatable automatically, setting to first page of DataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-datatable

When Im on other than frist page of DatTable and im using button from rowExpansion or even commandLink used in row, page is beeing set to first automatically

```html
<p:remoteCommand name="xyz" action="#{xBean.refreshXList()}" process="@this"/>
```

when this code is deleted DataTable page is not changing to first, ingoreAutoUpdate="true" not helping with it.

Comment: Have you tried `update="@none"` in your remote command?

Comment: or converting `action` into `actionListener`?

Comment: @Melloware still the same after that

Comment: @WoAiNii still the same after using actionListener

Comment: Try to post a full example of your table